# System.Net.IPEndPoint not marked as serializable in .Net Core 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

This is a frustrating issue, in .Net framework this is marked as serializable - but not in .Net core.  Am I missing something here?

Here is the code being run:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 5000);

    using (var mem = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var ser = new BinaryFormatter();
        ser.Serialize(mem, ep);                
    }

    Console.WriteLine("success");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Works fine in .Net framework, but .Net core 2.0 returns this error:

```
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: 'Type 
'System.Net.IPEndPoint' in Assembly 'System.Net.Primitives, Version=4.1.1.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' is not marked as 
serializable.'
```

Comment: I keep trying to impress on people that *usually* (unless you're doing something **very** specific, which isn't usually the case), it is a **bad idea** to use `BinaryFormatter` for... well, *anything*. So... IMO it is a moot point. I've checked, and it isn't marked serializable in .NET Core 3.0 preview, either. You *might* be able to fight it with serialization surrogates, but... frankly I'd suggest using a different serializer instead.

Comment: Thanks Marc, Json serialization fails for both too - but can work with .Net framework with a custom serializer.  Disappointing.

Comment: If I may offer an opinion flavoured by many years of experience with serialization APIs: stop *trying* to serialize `IPEndPoint`. That is an *implementation detail*. At the serialization level, you only want to serialize *data*. The *data* here might be, for example, a host/ip-address and a port. A `string` is good for that - for example `"somehost:1234"` - or a `string`/`int` pair: `host: "somehost", port: 1234`. Pretty-much *any* serializer will handle those. I've reached the conclusion that serialization should only involve basic types (`string`, `int` etc) and your **own** DTO types.

Comment: @MarcGravell why is it a bad idea to use BinaryFormatter? What's better way to serialize an object to byte[]? Thanks.

Comment: @KokHowTeh oh, let me count the ways... it is: incredibly brittle (unfriendly towards version changes, refactoring, type relocations, etc); framework-bound (not fully portable etc), *essentially* deprecated in .NET Core (although it kinda sorta exists) - so not good routes forward; it is slower and more inefficient than it needs to be; it is a known security hole (malicious payloads can make unexpected things happen, essentially RCE) - is that enough to start with? Better ways: I'd lean towards protobuf-net myself, but I am very biased

Comment: @MarcGravell I have used protobuf-net for a portion of my messaging with good results, although it comes with an overhead of attribute markers etc.  Much more lightweight, though.